# Density plot with multiple values per row

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have run into a problem I can't seem to solve. I have a dataframe that can be summarized with this:

```
peptide_sequence <- c("YKYTGFTG", "YNHRPDVRF", "MNALHHPPCS")

start_position <- c(5, 33, 79)

df <- data.frame(peptide_sequence, start_position)

df$peptide_length <- str_count(df$peptide_sequence)

df$end_position <- (df$start_position + df$peptide_length - 1)
```

These data basically describe the position of various peptides within a larger protein. I would now like to create a simple density plot by position in this larger protein (in this example from position 5-88). I haven't included the position column as I have tried a few different ways of putting it together, using the start and end position info, but none seem to work in a way that is able to be read properly by the geom_density function (which seems to be because I am trying to have multiple values from each row). The problem I am having is with re-working these data/putting together the start and end position data into a format that can be used to create the desired density plot.

For example, I would like first peptide sequence "YKYTGFTG" to count towards the positions 5:12, as indicated by the start and end positions.

One way these data could be translated would be basically ending up with a row for each position of each peptide. A manual example of how this dataframe could look is this:

```
peptide_sequence <- c("YKYTGFTG", "YKYTGFTG", "YKYTGFTG", "YKYTGFTG", "YKYTGFTG", "YKYTGFTG", "YKYTGFTG", "YKYTGFTG",
                      "YNHRPDVRF", "YNHRPDVRF", "YNHRPDVRF", "YNHRPDVRF", "YNHRPDVRF", "YNHRPDVRF", "YNHRPDVRF", "YNHRPDVRF", "YNHRPDVRF",
                      "MNALHHPPCS", "MNALHHPPCS", "MNALHHPPCS", "MNALHHPPCS", "MNALHHPPCS", "MNALHHPPCS", "MNALHHPPCS", "MNALHHPPCS", "MNALHHPPCS", "MNALHHPPCS")

position <- c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,
              33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41,
              79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88)

df <- data.frame(peptide_sequence, position)
```

This would then give the following plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = position)) + 
  geom_density()
```

[image]

The above plot is essentially what I am hoping to get to. The dataframe I am working with has many rows of peptides, such that I cannot manually convert it like I have above, so I am seeking a way that the conversion could be done, or an alternative way to re-work the data that would also be able to generate the same type of plot.
Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Can you add an example of the type of plot you're trying to get exactly, or at least how far your current plotting code gets you? I don't get how this would translate to a density plot, by which I'm assuming you mean something like [this](https://datavizcatalogue.com/methods/density_plot.html)

Comment: Hi @camille, 
You are right that a plot like the one linked is essentially what I am hoping to get, with the x axis being the length of the total protein. I have updated the question to include an example of how example data could be re-worked into a format that would generate the density plot that I am hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list column that is the `seq` from `start_position` to `end_position`. Unnesting this column will yield the desired results.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(position = map2(start_position, end_position, seq)) %>%
  unnest(position) %>%
  select(peptide_sequence, position)
#> # A tibble: 27 x 2
#>   peptide_sequence position
#>   <fct>               <int>
#> 1 YKYTGFTG                5
#> 2 YKYTGFTG                6
#> 3 YKYTGFTG                7
#> 4 YKYTGFTG                8
#> 5 YKYTGFTG                9
#> 6 YKYTGFTG               10
#> 7 YKYTGFTG               11
#> 8 YKYTGFTG               12
#> 9 YNHRPDVRF              33
#> 10 YNHRPDVRF             34
#> # ... with 17 more rows
```